# Auto sizing a datagrid with star-sized columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that's been generated from code.

```
DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Add some columns
{
    DataGridBoundColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
    column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
    column.Header = String.Format("Hello World {0}!", i);
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}

return dataGrid;
```

This results in a `DataGrid` of width `Double.NaN`, which is what I want, and it has the 3 columns, like I want, however, the columns do not size correctly. They each take up as little space as they can instead of filling the entire space of the `DataGrid`.

When I manually set the width of the `DataGrid`, the columns behave as they should, filling up the entire width and each having a size equal to one another.

Below is a picture of the erroneous `DataGrid`.

[image: Picture of DataGrid]

Answer (score 1):

You could try deferring the column population until the data grid's `Loaded` event has been fired (and then unhook the event handler).  However, it doesn't seem that the grid will update the column widths as the data grid is resized.  The computed widths only seem to be invalidated when the column collection is modified, when the items source changes, or when a column's visibility changes.

Comment: +1: This is at least a step in the right direction. I updated each column's width to `col.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);`, but as you said, it appears they don't update with resizing of the DataGrid.

Comment: You could try clearing the width of each column using `ClearValue` before updating it.  If you're setting it again, but the width was *already* `1*`, then it won't be treated as a change.  Looking at the source again, it does seem that changing the column widths should cause the "actual" widths to be recomputed.

Comment: Actually, in the `Loaded` event the width of each column is `Auto` I commented out the earlier width setter.